# Could a KDE plasma widget be converted into its own app (easily)?

Tags: application-development, kde, plasma, widgets

I've recently made the switch from KDE to Unity and I'm **really** missing one feature: the `FolderView` [Plasma widget](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Folder_Views) (Plasmoid?)

[image]

I know there's a screenlet called `Folderview` which can be [used under Unity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQarMD0JizQ&playnext=1&list=PLE7A6A54999D947F3&feature=results_main), but it's so buggy it's virtually usless (and even it if weren't it doesn't even come close to mimic all the features of KDE's `FolderView`)

So the question is: is there any way to easily *convert/translate* a Plasmoid into a stand alone app to be used in Unity? Or are plasmoids so dependent on the Plasma desktop it would be like writing a new app from scratch?

---

**Edit**: I've been using the `FolderView` screenlet and so far it's not *that* buggy, only a couple of crashes which have no actual effect on the system's behavior. Perhaps it'll do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conversion**

It would take a significant rewrite of the plasmoid's source as the plasmoid is built within the kde-plasma framework. You would have to modify the source (if possible) to replace these libraries with GTK or QT equivalents.

**Workaround**

It may not look quite as fancy as in plasma, but you could try `plasmoidviewer`, 
i.e.

```
plasmoidviewer APPLETNAME
```

This will run the applet in it's own window, but it will *require* a large part of the *kde libs* be installed.

As Cumulus007 suggests you can also then use ccsm (or other appropriate window manager settings dialog) to modify the appearance of the plasmoidviewer  - i.e. remove the frame and window title bar, and cause the window to always be below other windows. The result should look and behave a lot like a plasma plasmoid.

Comment: mutzmatron could you expand your answer a bit? How would this work? Also, I need to download the `kde-workspace-bin` package to run `plasmoidviewer`. What would this make to `Unity`, will it mess it up in any way? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK it will not influence unity at all - it will be no different to running any other QT application.

Comment: You can use ccsm to make the plasmoidviewer window behave as if it was a proper desktop widget.

Comment: Cheers @Cumulus007 - great idea.

Comment: Thanks both but I'm reluctant to try that because it means installing pretty much KDE in its entirety. The question still remains: how would one go about converting a KDE `plasmoid` to an app that could run in Unity. Cheers.

Comment: @Gabriel: in that case I think it would take a significant rewrite of the plasmoids source as the plasmoid is built within the kde-plasma framework. You would have to modify the source (if possible) to replace these libraries with GTK or QT equivalents.

Comment: @mutzmatron Ok, thanks a lot. If you put this comment as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one. Cheers.

Comment: @Gabriel: Done!